# Dynamic heat map rendering in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, heat-map, rendering

I have a large point dataset that I am publishing as a service. When zoomed out I would like to show the data as a heat map, only showing the actual points when zoomed right in. I know there are a couple of API's that can do heat map rendering client side (java, leaflet, Silverlight, etc) and the esri maps for office has a nice example as well. But is there any way to utilise a dynamic heat map renderer within ArcMap, maybe using python?

Currently I am using the point density tool to generate multiple raster layers with varying radius's and using scale dependencies to flick through them as you zoom in, you get a similar effect but this seems a little clunky and I am hoping there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Point Density tool, Line Density and Kernel Density can all be utilized in order to create a heat map. Point Density calculates the density of point features around each raster cell.  In comparison, Line Density calculates the density of the line features within a radius around each output cell.  Finally, Kernel Density uses an algorithm to calculate density of point features around each neighborhood which is determined by the points that you are measuring with your data.  Each of these tools will yield various results as far as the visual result of the map. Additionally, the application of a HeatMapRenderer to a ArcGisDynamicMapServiceLayer instead of a FeatureLayer may be able to help with the dynamic aspects of your problem.